# Large subset selection from data.frame

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset:

```
library(gtools)
a<-permutations(2,20,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
a<-as.data.frame(a)
```

And I have a matrix:

```
set.seed(123)
b<-replicate(5,sample(1:20,5, replace=T))
b<-t(b)
```

For each row of `'a'` I would like to select the columns specified by each column in `'b'`

to do so I run the following:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) sapply(1:N, function(y) a[i,c(as.vector(b[,y]))])
```

As a result I want a matrix or data.frame with the selected columns from `'a'` for each row of `'a'`

The problem is that this process is extremely slow. I would like to know if there is a faster way to do this.

The above example is do show how slow the process is. 
Here is a smaller example:

```
 library(gtools)
 a<-permutations(2,5,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
 a<-as.data.frame(a)



 set.seed(123)
  b<-replicate(5,sample(1:5,5, replace=T))
  b<-t(b)
```

here's what I want step by step:

```
1. select the i-th row in `'a'`
2. select the y-th column in `'b'`

3.select those elements in the first row of `'a'` that are specified by the first column in `'b'`

4. Repeat 2. and 3. until all columns of 'b' have been used.
```

This is done using:

```
sapply(1:N, function(y) a[i,c(as.vector(b[,y]))])
```

1. Repeat 1-4 for each row in `'a'`

This is done by adding the for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) sapply(1:ncol(b), function(y) a[i,c(as.vector(b[,y]))])
```

Comment: In your code, what is `N`?.  Also in the example dataset, `b`, there are repeat values.  I tried this on a smaller subset `a1 <- a[1:22,]; a1[,c(b)]`  May be I misunderstood the question.

Comment: thanks for your help. what you suggest is how to select columns from a1 based on b. this is indeed what I want to do, BUT: treat each column in 'b' as a vector specifying which columns to select from 'a'. - that's why I have the sapply(), and then do this for each row in 'a'. that's why I have the for loop

Comment: p.s. I edited my question and specified what N is.

Comment: Sorry, wouldn't `c(b)` gives you a vector.  I am not following the logic. Or do you want to it like this. index first row of `a` with 1st column of `b`, then 2nd column of `a` with 1st column `b`. and so on and again start the same process with 2nd column of `a`.

Comment: b is a matrix, each column in b specifies which elements to select from a. I want to do the selection for each column of b. separately. c(b) would create a large output but you cannot tell which columns correspond to which selection

Comment: I guess you are creating a lot of lists.  Using the small subset `a1`.  `res1 <- sapply(1:ncol(b), function(y) a1[22,c(as.vector(b[,y]))])` is same as `res2 <- matrix(unlist(a1[22,c(b)], use.names=F), ncol=5)`.  But, the output of `res1` is a list with 25 elements

Comment: you are right this solution works. but not if you do it for each column of a (for example using sapply()). it takes a lot of time. do you see what I mean?

Comment: Try: `a2 <- as.matrix(a1[,c(b)]);  lapply(split(a2, row(a2)), function(x) { matrix(x,ncol=ncol(b))})`

Comment: great, this is much faster, although still quite slow. but great, thanks! if you have any ideas how to speed it up even more, please let me know

Comment: okay.  Can i add this as an answer

Comment: How about keeping it in an array. `array(t(a2), dim=c(5,5,22))` only 22 rows for a1.

Comment: you mean instead of a2 <- as.matrix(a1[,c(b)])? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: `a1[,c(b)]` gives a `data.frame`.  I convert it to matrix so that I can split up easily.

Comment: yes but what do you mean by keeping it an array. you can submit your answer with the array suggestion and then I will see what you mean exactly. and I will accept your answer anyway because it helped

Comment: I just updated with the solution.  I guess the `array` option should be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a smaller subset of `a`

```
 a1 <- a[1:22,]
 a2 <- as.matrix(a1[,c(b)])

 res1 <- lapply(split(a2, row(a2)), function(x) { matrix(x,ncol=ncol(b))})
```

Or by keeping it in array

```
 arr1 <- array(t(a2), dim=c(5,5,22))

res1[[22]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    1    0    1    0
#[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    1    0    0    0    1
#[5,]    1    0    0    1    0

arr1[,,22]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    0    1    0
# [2,]    0    0    1    0    0
# [3,]    1    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    0    0    0    1
# [5,]    1    0    0    1    0
```